# iPhone UITextView position relative

Tags: iphone, layout, position, uitextview

i got a news page (a view) at my application and it has news' image and text. Text is in a UITextView and i want my text to start next to image and when the image ends continue from the down of the image, like the text is surrounding the image. i tried autoResizingMask but as i ve understood it is for the relations between subview and superview so it didnt work. Is there any way to do it ?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, `UITextView` doesn't support wrapping around other views. You can:

1. Split the text into two `UITextView`s
2. Use a `UIWebView`
3. Do your own drawing using `NSString`'s `drawInRect` or `drawAtPoint` methods.